# Connecting to freenode with Tor

Tags: tor, sasl

I need help with connecting to freenode with Tor. I generated SASL certificate and placed it into cert folder in HexChat's folder. Then I used my registered account and password and tried to connect but it said "SASL authentication failed". Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Freenode does not accept password-based authentication via Tor. You need to first connect directly, log in with password, and add the certificate fingerprint to NickServ.

Comment: yes, I already did that

Comment: Ok never mind I figured it out